# Firebase notification doesn't work on closed iOS RN application

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

First of all, I know there are already several conversations about this. But I couldn't find an answer that solved my problem.

I would like my react-native application to trigger when the user comes from a notification. On Android, I have no problem the trigger works when application is in background, foreground or even closed.

On iOS I can't figure out why but the trigger didn't works when the application is closed.

Here's my dependencies version :

- react-native: 0.59.3
- react-native-firebase: 5.1.1
- xCode: 10.2
- firebase: 5.0.3
- firebase-admin: 5.12.0

In my **App.js** I register listeners to handle notifications actions.

```
handleNotificationClicked = notificationOpen => {
        const { data } = notificationOpen.notification;
        console.log('DATA NOTIF');
        console.log(data);
        setParam(data.title);
        FCM.conditionalNavigate(data, data.title);
    };

    async createNotificationListeners() {
        /* If app is in foreground */
        this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification(notification => {});
        /*  If app is in background */
        this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened(this.handleNotificationClicked);
        /* If app is closed */
        const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
        console.log('notificationOpen', notificationOpen);
        if (notificationOpen) {
            console.log('HERE please');
            this.handleNotificationClicked(notificationOpen);
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const { setCurrentRoute } = this.props;
        const defaultRoute = NavigationService.initCurrentRoute();
        setCurrentRoute({ route: defaultRoute });
        await this.createNotificationListeners();
    }
```

Everything works well except for the case when the application is closed, my variable **notificationOpen** is always null.

Here's how I send the notification :

```
const sendMessage = async () => {
    const message = {
        notification: {
            title,
            body
        },
        data: {
            title,
            body
        },
        android: {
            ttl: 3600 * 1000,
            notification: {
                icon: 'stock_ticker_update',
                color: '#002559'
            }
        },
        apns: {
            payload: {
                aps: {
                    badge: 0
                }
            }
        },
        topic
    }

    try {
        console.info('index firestore message', message);
        await admin.messaging().send(message);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('sendMessage failed', err);
        throw err;
    }
};
```

I receive the notification but when I click on it, the getInitialNotification() method doesn't do anything ...

So I thought the problem was with my native code.

```
import Foundation
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    let bridge = RCTBridge(delegate: self, launchOptions: launchOptions)
    let rootView = RCTRootView(bridge: bridge, moduleName: "", initialProperties: nil)
    rootView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1)

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let rootViewController = UIViewController()
    rootViewController.view = rootView
    self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    didFinishLaunching = true

    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])

    FirebaseApp.configure()


    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    Messaging.messaging().useMessagingDelegateForDirectChannel = true
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

    self.requestAuthorization(for: application, launchOptions: launchOptions)


    RNSplashScreen.showSplash("LaunchScreen", inRootView: rootViewController.view)

    return true
  }

 private func requestAuthorization(for application: UIApplication, launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]

      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)

      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
  }

// MARK: - Notifications extention
extension AppDelegate {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
  }
}


  @available(iOS 10, *)
  extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    // iOS10+, called when presenting notification in foreground
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
      let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
      NSLog("[UserNotificationCenter] applicationState:  willPresentNotification: \(userInfo)")
      //TODO: Handle foreground notification
      completionHandler([.alert])
    }

    // iOS10+, called when received response (default open, dismiss or custom action) for a notification
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
      let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
      NSLog("[UserNotificationCenter] applicationState:  didReceiveResponse: \(userInfo)")
      //TODO: Handle background notification
      completionHandler()
    }
  }

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
  }

  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) { }
}
```

I took some code examples from my research but it still doesn't works.

Could anyone help me to figure out where is my mistake ? It would be really appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: @Doug Stevenson I have the same problem with you, everything works smoothly on Android, but not with iOS, the onforeground notification works, but for onclosed it doesn't work, have you found a solution?